# MNIST - Vanilla Neural Network - Why Cost Function is Increasing?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

I've been combing through this code for a week now trying to figure out why my cost function is increasing as in the following image. Reducing the learning rate does help but very little. Can anyone spot why the cost function isn't working as expected?

I realise a CNN would be preferable, but I still want to understand why this simple network is failing.
Please help:)

[image: Runaway Cost Function]

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_DATA/",one_hot=True)

def createPlaceholders():
    xph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (784, None))
    yph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (10, None))
    return xph, yph

def init_param(layers_dim):
    weights = {}
    L = len(layers_dim)

    for l in range(1,L):
        weights['W' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable('W' + str(l), shape=(layers_dim[l],layers_dim[l-1]), initializer= tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        weights['b' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable('b' + str(l), shape=(layers_dim[l],1), initializer= tf.zeros_initializer())

    return weights

def forward_prop(X,L,weights):
    parameters = {}
    parameters['A0'] = tf.cast(X,tf.float32)

    for l in range(1,L-1):
        parameters['Z' + str(l)] = tf.add(tf.matmul(weights['W' + str(l)], parameters['A' + str(l-1)]), weights['b' + str(l)])
        parameters['A' + str(l)] = tf.nn.relu(parameters['Z' + str(l)])

    parameters['Z' + str(L-1)] = tf.add(tf.matmul(weights['W' + str(L-1)], parameters['A' + str(L-2)]), weights['b' + str(L-1)])
    return parameters['Z' + str(L-1)]

def compute_cost(ZL,Y):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = tf.cast(Y,tf.float32), logits = ZL))
    return cost

def randomMiniBatches(X,Y,minibatch_size):
    m = X.shape[1]
    shuffle = np.random.permutation(m)
    temp_X = X[:,shuffle]
    temp_Y = Y[:,shuffle]

    num_complete_minibatches = int(np.floor(m/minibatch_size))

    mini_batches = []

    for batch in range(num_complete_minibatches):
        mini_batches.append((temp_X[:,batch*minibatch_size: (batch+1)*minibatch_size], temp_Y[:,batch*minibatch_size: (batch+1)*minibatch_size]))

    mini_batches.append((temp_X[:,num_complete_minibatches*minibatch_size:], temp_Y[:,num_complete_minibatches*minibatch_size:]))

    return mini_batches

def model(X, Y, layers_dim, learning_rate = 0.001, num_epochs = 20, minibatch_size = 64):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    costs = []

    xph, yph = createPlaceholders()
    weights = init_param(layers_dim)
    ZL = forward_prop(xph, len(layers_dim), weights)
    cost = compute_cost(ZL,yph)
    optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            minibatches = randomMiniBatches(X,Y,minibatch_size)
            epoch_cost = 0

            for b, mini in enumerate(minibatches,1):
                mini_x, mini_y = mini
                _,c = sess.run([optimiser,cost],feed_dict={xph:mini_x,yph:mini_y})
                epoch_cost += c
            print('epoch: ',epoch+1,'/ ',num_epochs)

            epoch_cost /= len(minibatches)
            costs.append(epoch_cost)

    plt.plot(costs) 
    print(costs)



X_train = mnist.train.images.T
n_x = X_train.shape[0]
Y_train = mnist.train.labels.T
n_y = Y_train.shape[0]
layers_dim = [n_x,10,n_y]

model(X_train, Y_train, layers_dim)
```

Comment: To which values were you reducing the learning rate? Which learning rates did you try?

Comment: I varied it between 0.01 until 0.0001. As @Alexander said the reason for the problem was the dimensions of my tensors in the cost function. If I transpose them everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going to much into how you draw the mini batches: I think the problem is you are for some reason defining axis 1 of `xph` and `yph` as batch dimension (and feeding accordingly) while the computational graph of the network expects axis 0 to be the batch dimension like it is usually done.

So your forward propagation is actually performed along the batch dimension, which does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you. If I transpose the labels and logits in the cost function it corrects the problem.

Comment: I am glad to help. This is a good example for a bug that is quite obvious for people who see the code for the first time, but really hard to find for the one who originally wrote the code, since this is something you would not look for.